# php boolean value as argument throws encoding error

Tags: php

When I try to put a boolean value as a parameter in a functionc call, I get that I am missing a property

```
// try to get orders
try {
    $order = new Order($auth_login, $auth_password, $live_mode);
    $orders = $order->findOrdersBySubscriptionId($sessionId, $subscriptionId, (bool) false);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

This gives this error:

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'onlyOnGoing' property
        Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Session] => 12345
                        [SubscriptionId] => 30520
                        [OnlyOnGoing] => 
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I have also tried (instead of `(bool) false`):

`FALSE`, `False`, `false`

None work!

**EDIT:**

I looked through `Orders` and found this part:

```
public function findOrdersBySubscriptionId($session, $subscriptionId, $onlyOnGoing) {
    try {
        $result = $this->client->findOrdersBySubscriptionId(array("Session" => $session, "SubscriptionId" => $subscriptionId, "OnlyOnGoing" => $onlyOnGoing));
        return $result;
    } catch (Except $e) {
        return array("Error" => $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Where I changed `"onlyOnGoing" => $onlyOnGoing` to `"OnlyOnGoing" => $onlyOnGoing`.

Now I get this error (I also changed output from `print_r` to `var_dump`):

```
object(SoapFault)#2668 (10) {
["message":protected]=>
string(58) "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'onlyOnGoing' property"
["trace":"Exception":private]=>
array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
        [0]=>
        string(26) "findOrdersBySubscriptionId"
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
            ["Session"]=>
            string(36) "4D398084-9B08-38A3-362E-880111364DD8"
            ["SubscriptionId"]=>
            int(30520)
            ["OnlyOnGoing"]=>
            bool(false)
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what does `findOrdersBySubscriptionId()` do?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: We don't know anything about the class `Order`. How should we be able to tell you why something is going wrong when a method of an instance of that class is invoked?

Comment: Also, there's no need to cast a `bool` value to `bool`. It already is a `bool`.

Comment: Can you show us the part of your method where `OnlyOnGoing` is being set?

Comment: @localheinz See edit!

Comment: @DrRoach See edit please!

Comment: Change the `onlyOnGoing` key back to snake case like I've shown and then please let us know what happens inside of the `findOrdersBySubscriptionId()` call.

Comment: Maybe it wants string "false"?